# SQL: Aggregate one column based on another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stumped with this query.  I have a deal table with deals for different doctors.  There is a many to many between deals and doctors (more than one doctor per deal is possible).  I need to find the deals with the closest doctors to a given user's latitude and longitude.  I have a stored procedure that takes care of finding the distance.

```
    Select d.dealID, do.doctorID,
    dbo.fn_latlongdist($userlat,$userlong,do.doctorLatitude,do.doctorLongitude) as distance
    From y_Deals d
    JOIN y_deals_doctor dd ON dd.dealID = d.dealID
    JOIN Doctor do on dd.doctorID = do.doctorID 
    ORDER BY distance
```

Now I want to group by the dealID so I don't return multiple deals.  Problem is I want to return the doctorID with the minimum distance. Doesn't seem like there's any aggregate function that would surround doctorID that would return the doctorID with the minimum distance column.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Can't you just select top row? Select Top 1 ...

Comment: does the doctor table contain some information about it's location?

Comment: @amit_g I don't want just the top 1, I want a list of deals by distance, but I want to know the closest doctor attached to each one

Comment: @leslie the doctor table has the doctor's lat and longitude as you can see.  It also has the city and state of the doctor which I need for output with this application

Comment: For each DealID, you want only one DoctorID, with the lowest distance. What happens when two DoctorIDs offering the same deal have exactly the same distance which happens to be the lowest distance for the deal?

Comment: @user662852 this is highly unlikely, but I see how the concern might make the SQL logic complicated.  In this case, if this situation arose, it wouldn't matter to me which doctor it chose

Comment: What version of SQL server do you use?

Comment: Posted SQL that may work for you. Let us know what you find.

Comment: What is this `$userlat` syntax? Is it valid SQL?

Comment: @Martin: I think it can be valid when included in php script or when run with `sqlcmd`. That is, it's probably not valid by itself, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
Select * From
(
    Select
          d.dealID
        , do.doctorID
        , dbo.fn_latlongdist($userlat, $userlong, do.doctorLatitude, do.doctorLongitude) as Distance
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.dealID ORDER BY dbo.fn_latlongdist($userlat, $userlong, do.doctorLatitude, do.doctorLongitude)) AS RowNumber
    From
        y_Deals d
    JOIN
        y_deals_doctor dd ON dd.dealID = d.dealID
    JOIN
        Doctor do on dd.doctorID = do.doctorID 
) T
Where
    T.RowNumber = 1
```

UPDATE:

```
;With AllData As
(
    Select
          d.dealID
        , do.doctorID
        , dbo.fn_latlongdist($userlat, $userlong, do.doctorLatitude, do.doctorLongitude) as Distance
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.dealID ORDER BY dbo.fn_latlongdist($userlat, $userlong, do.doctorLatitude, do.doctorLongitude)) AS RowNumber
    From
        y_Deals d
    JOIN
        y_deals_doctor dd ON dd.dealID = d.dealID
    JOIN
        Doctor do on dd.doctorID = do.doctorID 
)
,DrCount As
(
    Select
          dealID
        , Count(Distinct doctorID) as doctorCount
    From
        AllData
    Group By
        dealID
)
Select
    *
From
    AllData A
Inner Join
    DrCount C
On
    A.dealID = C.dealID
Where
    A.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: this works.  Is there any way it could return a column that displays how many doctors were originally attached to the deal?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the technique discussed in http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/.  It doesn't depend on ROW_NUMBER(), which isn't available for a lot of DB engines.

Here's an example where distance is a column in the doctor table instead of a calculated function.  Adapt as needed:

```
SELECT
  Doctors.ID, DoctorName, Distance, DealName
FROM
  (SELECT DealID, Min(Doc.Distance) as Dist
   FROM  DoctorDeals, Doctors as Doc
   WHERE  DoctorDeals.DoctorID = Doc.ID
   GROUP BY  DealID) as T, 
  DoctorDeals, Deals, Doctors
WHERE
  T.Dist = Doctors.Distance
AND
  T.DealID = DoctorDeals.DealID
AND
  DoctorDeals.DoctorID = Doctors.ID
AND 
  DoctorDeals.DealID = Deals.ID
```